# Elongate View when another one is being hidden

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-animation

I am currently trying to achieve a certain animation:
I have a view(LinearLayout) which should be hidden / shown when a fab-button is pressed, and the view(RecyclerView) below this view(LinearLayout) should elongate or shorten so it fits the screen again. The LinearLayout is being pushed up, the RecyclerView below should therefore elongate in the perfect way so it looks like they would stick together.

Currently I have custom animations which look like the following:

slide_down.xml

```
<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

slide_up.xml

```
<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="-100%"/>
```

The Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="app.chrono.worker.TabbedActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <!-- THIS ONE IS THE LINEAR LAYOUT I WAS TALKING ABOUT -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_search_whole"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/search_grid"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <!-- took out some code here -->


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

<!-- THIS IS THE RECYCLERVIEW -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_below="@id/ll_search_whole"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Though, the RecyclerView is acting laggy and does not stick at all to the LinearLayout.

How can I achieve my desired animation?

Comment: Please share the layout with the LinearLayout and its neighbouring RecyclerView

Comment: I added it, check please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the Transitions framework? For this approach, the parent `RelativeLayout` needs an id, let's assume it's `android:id="@+id/sceneRoot"`. 
We set up all relevant `View`s as fields of the `Activity`/ the `Fragment`:

```
private ViewGroup sceneRoot = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.sceneRoot);
private View ll_search_whole = findViewById(R.id.ll_search_whole);
```

So here's how to hide the `LinearLayout`:

```
TransitionSet tSet = new TransitionSet();
tSet.addTransition(new Fade());
tSet.addTransition(new ChangeBounds());

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(sceneRoot, tSet);
ll_search_whole.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This should result in a smooth animation. If `ViewGroup`s like the `RecyclerView` transition somehow laggardly one can try calling `setTransitionGroup(true);` on them.

Comment: The method tSet.add() does not exist, is it addTransition();?

Comment: @ProgFroz - my bad (thought I knew it by heart)

Comment: Okay works, but not perfectly. Firstly, I get an error message when I scroll the recyclerView and click the fab to animate. Secondly I would like the LinearLayout to be pushed up and down (like in the R.anim files) + this nice smooth layout, how can I combine that?
Thanks for the TransitionSet btw, did not know this exists :)

Comment: @ProgFroz - Slide is useful for translate animations. The basic point seems to be that right after you call `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(sceneRoot, tSet);`, you set the desired end values for visibility but also for position or size. Sorry I must be off soon but here's a link to my [favourite tutorial](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html) by A.J. Lockwood